# output format of float

Tags: lisp, scheme

I am using MIT/GNU Scheme. If I calculate two integers' quotient and the quotient is float, the output is not a float number, but two number's expression, like: **12222222222222232/2344444444412**. How can I get a float format output?

Comment: The result is not a "float" but a ratio.  What you want is the conversion of an (exact) ratio to an (inexact) floating point number.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`exact->inexact`](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Exactness.html) function:

```
(let ((x (/ 5 7)))
    (let ((f (exact->inexact x)))
        (display f)))
```

Comment: Greg, please take a look at [Racket language questions tagging: tags "plt-scheme" and "racket"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74042/147036). Thanks.

Comment: @Yasir: I'm afraid I don't understand how that question relates to this answer.

Comment: `exact->inexact` is a legacy (and wrongly named) name for `inexact`.